# Issues with express.static() to load an image on my front end which is in a folder on my back end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, directory

My app displays items on one of its pages. each item has an image, number and name. i have the image stored in a folder on the back end called "uploads". I can see the image there in the folder and from the node back end I'm supplying the client an object with item image link, name, and plu.
all the react front end is in one folder and the node server in another, each within the same folder level.
project/client/(several folders deep)/page.js - this is the page which is trying to display the image from
project/server/uploads/image.jpg

i have my express.static set up like this.

`app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));`

and my image tag set up like

`<img src="/uploads/image.jpg">`

if I use the localhost link in the src I can display the image. i.e.
`src="http://localhost:3001/uploads/image.jpg"`

this is fine for development but when the project launches I think I will run into some issues. I want to make sure I do it correctly.
Anyone got any ideas? I've tried everything I could think of.
this is what I get when I copy the relative path in vs code:

**Back end image:**

`Server\uploads\1681390333390.jpg`

**Front end file requesting:**

`work-mate\src\Main\PLUDashboard\revision\bakery\BakeRevision.js`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the server-domain in the frontend app if you want to access resources from the backend.

I'd recommend having the backend-domain set up as an environment variable that's set to `localhost:3000` when developing locally, and `example.server.com` on the live version of the frontend.

Using different .env files can be done by naming them depending on which npm script you'll run:

- `npm start: .env.development`
- `npm run build: .env.production`

Comment: `const grabImagePath =`${req.protocol}://${req.hostname}:${req.app.get('port')}/uploads/${imageFileName}`;`

Would building the link on the back end work just as well when deployed? it builds the correct http://localhost:3001/uploads/image.jpg at the moment and displays the image. when I put my server somewhere else would it build the correct URL still? 
I'm still fairly new to back end work.

Comment: Yes, that should work!